# Removing Initialization Vector from Cipher Text

Tags: apex, integration, crypto

```
public static string getencRequest(){

       String PLAIN_Request = 'merchant_id=90578&order_id=456&currency=INR&amount=1.00&redirect_url=https://ceptes-sf-webhook-developer-edition.ap27.force.com/response&cancel_url=https://google.com&language=EN&integration_type=iframe_Normal';                      
                                          
       String text = PLAIN_Request;
       Blob cryptoKey = Blob.valueOf('BAC7F80E25DA1826EF7635E3DE6B154F');
       Blob key = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', cryptoKey );
       Blob data = Blob.valueOf(text);
       String b64Data = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);
                                          
       Blob ciphertextAndIV = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);
       Blob plaintext = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, ciphertextAndIV);
       String b64Decrypted = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(plaintext);
                                          
       String encodedCiphertextAndIV = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(ciphertextAndIV);
       String encodedCiphertext = encodedCiphertextAndIV.substring(32);
       String encodedIV = encodedCiphertextAndIV.substring(0,32);
       system.debug('encodedCiphertext'+encodedCiphertext);
       system.debug('encodedCiphertextAndIV'+encodedCiphertextAndIV);

       return encodedCiphertext;
}
```

How can I remove the Initialization Vector from the Encoded request?

3rd party decryption tool link below

https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/aesCheck.jsp
working key = BAC7F80E25DA1826EF7635E3DE6B154F

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's unclear what your page is trying to do. Is it in EBC or CBC mode? Does it use PKCS7 padding? The methods provided by Salesforce support only CBC/PKCS7 mode. If you don't want an IV, you have to provide your own IV, which might happen to be all zeroes, for example.

Here's a stripped down version of what you wrote to get an encrypted value:

```
public string getencRequest(){
    String PLAIN_Request = 'merchant_id=90578&order_id=456&currency=INR&amount=1.00&redirect_url=https://ceptes-sf-webhook-developer-edition.ap27.force.com/response&cancel_url=https://google.com&language=EN&integration_type=iframe_Normal';                      
    String text = PLAIN_Request;
    Blob key = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex('BAC7F80E25DA1826EF7635E3DE6B154F');
    Blob iv = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex('0'.repeat(32));
    Blob ciphertext = Crypto.encrypt('AES128', key, iv, Blob.valueOf(text));
    return EncodingUtil.convertToHex(ciphertext);
}
System.debug(getencRequest());
```

Which produces the output in hex:

```
7ecf63f260d3dd0b6009f976f63540d7
4dd4ad6d2c325cd492d49e3cfe907532
01e16034a90d24f043d461baea0d270f
049edabb1f2ee630c9d204d8a9efba02
51afdb9aca592868e2a584cfd77372c0
d5d85e1e7b23441cfd62faae389be5cb
a9b3a0e2fcb9f23169e1a9cddce2dd1e
0c2bea1be00a92f0b7e6eb7bec5f8d08
5f14ca9452f7318cc777306cdc1a38c0
7509c554c90d2d4ac601c323676f4ecc
5fca1ee02313b070f278b11738084fdb
67fbb77a5a05820be9807607c3a04fd6
77bbd31f77fdd3ea4035b140a09ec101
37996a24db0cdc90fbba146115157e1f
```

Trying this in an [online tool](https://the-x.cn/en-US/cryptography/Aes.aspx) that supports AES-128/CBC/PKCS7, I get:

[image: Successfully Decrypted text]

So, in summary, if you don't want an IV in the text itself, use Crypto.encrypt and provide an IV of your own.